# The Ideal given by the kernel of map $ f \in R \mapsto f(0,0) \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$ is not finitely generated for this particular polynomial subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, polynomial-rings

In the following problem, $R$-module means left $R$-module and $R$ is a ring.

I have already proven these facts that may or not be needed:

-Show that an $R$-module $ M$ is finitely generated if and only if there exists a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules $R^n → M$, for some $n$.

-Every quotient of a finitely generated module is again fnitely generated.

I am trying to prove  the following:

Now set $R \subseteq \mathbb C[X,Y]$ be the subring of all polynomials $f \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$ that can
be written as $f = g(X)+X ·h(X,Y)$. (Equivalent: a polynomial $f = \sum a_{ij}X^iY^j$  is in $R$ if and only all coeffcients $a_{0,j}=0 $ for $j > 0$). $R $ is a subring of $\mathbb C[X,Y]$.

**a. Let $I \subset R$ be the kernel of the evaluation map $R \rightarrow C$ given by$ f \mapsto f(0,0)$. Show that the ideal $ I$ is not finitely generated.**

**b. Conclude that in general a submodule of a finitely generated module need not be finitely
generated**

**This is my try:**

a) **First of all, a remark: Is it a typo that its written $f = g(X)+X ·h(X,Y)$? Shouldn't it be $f(X,Y) = g(X)+X ·h(X,Y)$? And is there any particular reason for using capital letters?**

Let $ev(f):=f(0,0)$ denote the evaluation map

$I= \text{Ker (ev)}=\{f \in R: ev(f)=f(0,0)=0\}=\{ f(x,y)=g(x)+x·h(x,y): g(0)=0\}$

I guess I can proceed by absurd suppose that I is finitely generated. then $\exists$ polynomials $f_1, f_2,...,f_n \in I$ such that $\forall f \in I, f=\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_if_i$  with $r_i \in R$

b) I guess I could try to use any of the previous 3 propositions, but I don't really see how

**I am stuck here, I have no idea what to do next. Any help is appreciated**
BTW Still waiting for a less convoluted solution

Comment: One possible approach: since $R / I \simeq \mathbb{C}$, you get that $I / I^2$ is an $R / I$-module, i.e. a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.  If you can show that vector space is infinite-dimensional, that would make it impossible for $I$ to be finitely generated as an $R$-module.  (Haven't checked the details to see whether this is a workable solution, though.)

Comment: Note that every $g\in\mathbb{C}[X]$ can be written as a product of some $(x-c_i),\,c_i\in\mathbb{C}$, and $g(0)=0$ iff one of the $c_i$ in its decomposed form is 0. Thus the ideal you give is exactly the ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: @kotowh $xy$ is in the ideal, but since $y \notin R$, $xy$ is not a multiple of $x$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you cite what properties are you using in your suggestion? Like where does the isomorphism comes from ?, How does that imply that $I/I^2$ is an $R/I$-module? Why and how are you quotienting w.r.t to $I^2$? Why is $R/I$-module a vector space (is that imply becuase somehow R/I is a field?)?

Comment: @some_math_guy Since the evaluation morphism $R \to \mathbb{C}$ is surjective, you get $R / I \simeq \mathbb{C}$.  As for why $I / I^2$ is an $R/I$-module, that would be a good exercise to do (it's generally true, whether $R/I$ is a field or not).  And as for why I'm considering $I / I^2$ in the first place: it's a common trick to reduce statements about modules or ideals to statements about vector spaces, where you can take advantage of linear algebra theory such as uniqueness of dimension, etc.

Comment: @DanielSchepler what is $I^2$, considering I is a set? Cartesian product?

Comment: OK, I guess you haven't gotten to that point yet.  If $I$ is an ideal of a ring $R$, then $I^2$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $\{ xy \mid x \in I, y \in I \}$.  (More generally, if $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then $IJ$ is the ideal generated by $\{ xy \mid x \in I, y \in J \}$.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an outline of a possible approach for proving $I$ is not finitely generated:

- First, show that for each $f \in R$, in fact you can write $f$ in the form $c + X g(X, Y)$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $g \in \mathbb{C}[X, Y]$.  Also, $I$ is the ideal of polynomials of this form where $c = 0$.
- Now for the meat of the argument: define a function $\psi : I \to \mathbb{C}[Y]$ which takes $X g(X, Y) \in I$ to $g(0, Y)$.  In other words, $\psi(f)$ takes the coefficients $a_{1,0}, a_{1,1}, a_{1,2}, a_{1,3}, \ldots$ of $X, XY, XY^2, XY^3, \ldots$ in $f$ and returns $a_{1,0} + a_{1,1} Y + a_{1,2} Y^2 + a_{1,3} Y^3 + \cdots$.
- Show that $\psi$ respects addition.  Also, if $\lambda = c_0 + X g_0(X, Y) \in R$ and $f = X g_1(X, Y) \in I$, then $\psi(\lambda f) = c_0 \psi(f) = \lambda(0, 0) \psi(f)$.
- Now, start as you did and suppose, for sake of contradiction, that $I$ were finitely generated, i.e. suppose there were $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in I$ such that every $f \in I$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i f_i$ for some $\lambda_i \in R$.  Then by the above, $\psi(f) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(0,0) \psi(f_i)$, which is in the $\mathbb{C}$-linear span of $\{ \psi(f_1), \psi(f_2), \ldots, \psi(f_n) \}$ (where $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$).
- From here, you should be able to derive a contradiction.

---

As for part (b): Can you think of some particular $R$-module which $I$ is contained in?  For that $R$-module, is it finitely generated?

---

(This argument is a concrete form of a special case of the general trick I hinted at in the comments, where we reduce questions about generators of a module $M$ to questions about a spanning set of a vector space $M / JM$, where $J$ is some ideal such that $R / J$ is a field.  In this particular case, we use $M = I$ and $J = I$, and consider the vector space $I / I^2$ over the field $R / I \simeq \mathbb{C}$.  Then in this case, it turns out $I / I^2 \simeq \mathbb{C}[Y]$ where the isomorphism is closely related to the map $\psi$ defined above.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the second bullet, should $\psi$ map to $g(1,Y)$?. You put $g(0,Y)$ , isn't that making everything 0?

Comment: Why do we define this $\psi$ for?. In the third bullet after applying $\psi$ , i still have a finite linear span, so where can the contradiction possibly come from? I thought I had to get somehting infinitely generated

Comment: No, for example $X + XY + X^2 + X^3 Y^2 = X (1 + Y + X + X^2 Y^2) \mapsto 1 + Y$.

Comment: Well, what do you know about the span of finitely many elements of $\mathbb{C}[Y]$?

Comment: They are still of finite dimension?

Comment: Right - so is it possible that the span is all of $\mathbb{C}[Y]$?

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: So now, if you can come up with a separate argument that everything in $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ should be in the image of $\psi$, then you'll have the contradiction you were looking for.

Comment: that is I have to prove that it is surjective?

Comment: Regarding b) i was thinking in $R$ as an $R$-module, but then what would  the generator be? The unity of the module $1_R$? Wait, by the way  , then is it true that any ring (with a unity) is finitely generated? In that case C[Y] as a ring is also finitely generated? But then non-finitely generated rings do not exist?

Comment: Yes, a (unital) ring $R$ is always finitely generated as an $R$-module, with generating set $\{ 1_R \}$.  So $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}[Y]$-module; but it's not finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-module.

Comment: Why isn't it generated as a C-module?

Comment: For a field $K$, a $K$-module being finitely generated is equivalent to the vector space being finite-dimensional (since the latter is equivalent to having a finite set which spans the vector space, and then that's just a restatement of the module being finitely generated).

Comment: Why do I need to define this $\psi$ map that is not even an homomorphism to solve the problem?

Comment: And any idea how can I show the surjectivity of $\psi$ ?

Comment: Do the defined properties make $\psi$ a linear map?Because why would the conclusion for the image of $psi(f)$ translate to $f$? At the end is $f$ that I need to show that cannot be written as that finite linear combination

Comment: To show surjectivity of $\psi$: for example, can you come up with $f \in I$ such that $\psi(f) = Y^{10} + 3 Y^5 - 5 Y^2 + 1$?

Comment: 1) $X(\psi(f))$ So in general for $h(y) \in \mathbb C[Y]$, I can always write it as $h(x,y)=h(y)=h(0,y)$ and so $f(x,y)=xh(x,y)$ is in the preimage: $\psi(f(x,y))=\psi(xh(x,y))=h(0,y)=h(y)$ Looks good?

Comment: 2) Is it correct to say that $\psi$ is a linear map (homo of vector spaces) when i view $I$ as a $\mathbb C$ vector space, so$\psi: I \rightarrow \mathbb C[Y]$ ?

Comment: As for why I defined $\psi$ -- the basic idea of the proof is to show that $X, XY, XY^2, XY^3, \ldots$ are "$R$-linearly independent" in $I$, so I needed to give a name to the operation of extracting just that part of an element of $I$.  Another way of stating the proof: with $\psi$ being surjective and having the specified linearity-like properties, if $I$ were a finitely generated $R$-module then $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ would be a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-module as well; but we know that $\mathbb{C}[Y]$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: How does $ I $ being finitely generated an R-module (by suposition) translates into $\mathbb C[Y]$ being finitely generated $\mathbb C-module$ ? I feel we need to see $I $ as a $\mathbb C$-module as well?

Comment: You quote a previous result "Every quotient of a finitely generated module is again fnitely generated."  It's a similar situation here, except that here we're dealing with a relation between modules over two different rings; but the proof is very similar.